# my python code write in a temporary data base

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a python code that write/read data in/from a MySQL DB. The problem is that the table still empty even after I write in it. And when I close the program I loose all the data.
this is how I created the tables:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (id INT UNSIGNED NOT  NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,LastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,Post VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,RasID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=INNODB;")
```

this is how I insert data in the tables:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s);",(UserName, UserLastName, UserPost, int(data['RasID'])))
```

and this how I select data from the tables:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE Name= %s;",(Jmsg['face'],))
```

this what I get after inserting data in the table and  the program still running:

```
mysql> select * from employees;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

NB:  I can select data after inserting it  when the program still running but as I mentioned the table is empty. So, is the code write in a temporary table or what?

Comment: Do you call `connection.commit()`? Do you close your database manually by calling `connection.close()`? Alternatively, do you create your `connection` object in a `with` statement?

Comment: i didn't use connection.commit() this is why thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
connection.commit()
```

MySQL Connector/Python, which you're probably using here, does not autocommit which means that you have do it manually to "push" changes to database.

You may want to `commit` after every `execute` but you may also try to run it sometimes to conserve your bandwidth (but then you risk that you lose your changes when something went wrong).

Answer (score 1):

A transaction in a database takes generally no effect until it is commited.
I don't know about MySQL in Python, but I do know that `sqlite3`'s `Connection` instances have a `commit` method, that will write the transaction into the database.

In addition, when working with `sqlite3`, closing the connection by calling `Connection.close()` or (by leaving a `with` block, I think) should write the current transaction.
But anyway, it's bad practice to leave an object that was opened open.
And by "bad practice", I mean "dangerous and prone to bugs".